# Как преобразовать число с лишними символами в нормальный вид?

Tags: javascript

Число вида 27 348.00 ₽, необходимо получить 27348

Comment: Что конкретно не получилось?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Число вида 27 348.00 ₽, необходимо получить 27348

Выбрать только нужные числа... Убрать пробелы и преобразовать в число.

```js
const str = '27 348.00 ₽'
const v = +str.match(/[\d\s]*/)[0].replace(' ', '')
console.log(v)
```

Comment: А как же копеечки? Они жеж рубль берегут(по легенде)

Comment: @SwaD, не скрою... Я думал про них. :) Но решил воздержаться и дождаться ответной реакции от ТСа...

Comment: Ну вроде как твой ответ устроил, возможно копейки и не нужны в выводе вовсе... з.ы. минус не мой, я тут по талончкику "только спросить" )

Comment: @SwaD, Но уже какой-то хейтер, как всегда, заминусовал... :)